# Vue.js - Referencing input inside a modal to update Firestore database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arguments, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component

[image: Comp.js]

So the image above is my code inside a comp.js (Vue component) when the user clicks 'Update' button, it will grab the updated input and push it to firestore.

I put v-on:emit on every single input and I tried to reference it on the 'Update' button.

[image: HTML file]

This is my modal inside the HTML file, I tried to connect the function from comp.js to function.js.

[image: function.js]

However, the methods above didn't work and it gave me the error below.

[image: Error]

I'm not really sure how to grab the value from each input and connect

**UPDATED CODE BASED ON ITTUS'S SUGGESTION:**

So based on the Ittuss suggestion below, I tried to pass over to items through the emit inside the Update button, I did this because I want to pass all the input values above the button to update the Firestore database.

[image: Comps.js]

I changed the cuisedit to this:

[image: html]

And I updated the function in the .js to this:

[image: .js]

However, I received an error saying that I didn't reference correctly.

[image]

Do you know why it isn't grabbing the value emitted from the button?

Answer (score 1):

In your cuiseedit component, `$emit` should contain only 1 additional parameter:

```
<button @click="$emit('some-change', obj2.id)"></button>
```

and in component:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <cuisedit v-if="showModal" :obj2="cuisinemodal" @some-change="updateData">
  </cuisedit>
</transition>

updateData: function (id) {
  firestore.collection("koreanbap-cuisines").doc(id).update()....
}
```

**Note**

If you want to pass more data, you should wrap them to an object

```
<button @click="$emit('some-change', {id: obj2.id, event: $event})"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. We will let you know if it works!

Comment: Hi Ittus, I updated the code from your suggestion but I got another error, could you take a look at the updated question above? Thank you.